# Android HTTPS Connection

Tags: android, ssl, https

How to make HTTPS connection with server using Verisign 2048 Bit SSL Certificate ? Verisign certificates are available in root list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html

Generally, developer.android.com has a search bar at top right, which is very smart.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It uses HttpsURLConnection. I was looking for solution using HttpClient.

Comment: Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.

For Gingerbread and better, HttpURLConnection is the best choice. Its simple API and small size makes it great fit for Android. Transparent compression and response caching reduce network use, improve speed and save battery. New applications should use HttpURLConnection; it is where we will be spending our energy going forward. - Taken from Google Developer Blog.

Comment: @ArjunPatel I have some questions. I went through link posted my Peter. 
1. What is Keystore? 2. In order to implement HTTPS in my app what are the requirements do I need to know according to the developer.android.com link (above) from my webserver programmers team.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried a couple of days 
I'm finally get the answer 
so I would like to post here my steps and all my code in order to help someone else.

1) to get the certificate of the site you want to connect

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect ${MY_SERVER}:443 2>&1 |  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > mycert.pem
```

2)to create your key you need BouncyCastle library you can download [here](http://bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar)

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias 0 -file mycert.pem -keystore “store_directory/mykst“ -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath “directory_of_bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar” -storepass mypassword
```

3) to check if the key was created

```
keytool -list -keystore "carpeta_almacen/mykst" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "directory_of_bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass mypassword
```

and you should see something like this :

> Tipo de almacén de claves: BKS
>   Proveedor de almacén de claves: BC
>
> Su almacén de claves contiene entrada 1
>
> 0, 07-dic-2011, trustedCertEntry,
>
> Huella digital de certificado (MD5):
>
> 55:FD:E5:E3:8A:4C:D6:B8:69:EB:6A:49:05:5F:18:48

4)then you need to copy the file "mykst" into the directory "res/raw" (create it if does not exist) in your android project.

5)add the permissions to in the android manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

6) here the code!

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cargar contenido" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#4888ef">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/output"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyHttpClient**

```
package com.example.https;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    final Context context;

    public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
        // to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            // Trust manager / truststore
            KeyStore trustStore=KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

            // If we're on an OS version prior to Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) then use the standard way to get the system
            //   trustStore -- System.getProperty() else we need to use the special name to get the trustStore KeyStore
            //   instance as they changed their trustStore implementation.
            if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.compareTo("4.0") < 0) {
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory=TrustManagerFactory
                        .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                FileInputStream trustStoreStream=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"));
                trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, null);
                trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
                trustStoreStream.close();
            } else {
                trustStore=KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
            }

            InputStream certificateStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykst);
            KeyStore keyStore=KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            try {
                keyStore.load(certificateStream, "mypassword".toCharArray());
                Enumeration<String> aliases=keyStore.aliases();
                while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String alias=aliases.nextElement();
                    if (keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getType().equals("X.509")) {
                        X509Certificate cert=(X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
                        if (new Date().after(cert.getNotAfter())) {
                            // This certificate has expired
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // This occurs when there is an incorrect password for the certificate
                return null;
            } finally {
                certificateStream.close();
            }

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory=KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "mypassword".toCharArray());

            return new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore, "mypassword", trustStore);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.https;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private View loading;
    private TextView output;
    private Button button;

    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CargaAsyncTask().execute(new Void[0]);
            }
        });
    }

    class CargaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Instantiate the custom HttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
            // Execute the GET call and obtain the response
            HttpResponse getResponse;
            String resultado = null;
            try {
                getResponse = client.execute(get);
                HttpEntity responseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();
                resultado = convertStreamToString(is);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultado;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setEnabled(true);
            if (result == null) {
                output.setText("Error");
            } else {
                output.setText(result);
            }
        }

    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * Reader.read(char[] buffer) method. We iterate until the
         * Reader return -1 which means there's no more data to
         * read. We use the StringWriter class to produce the string.
         */
        if (is != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it could be useful for someone else!!
**enjoy it!**