# Use simple DefaultHttpClient or a keystore created with BouncyCastle bundled in the app

Tags: android, ssl, https

The server to which the app connected had a temporary certificate, or something like that. I am only taking care of the Android app and in order to make the https web service calls, the app used the unsafe implementation of the interface `X509TrustManager`. Now the server certificate has been fixed and has a final certificate.

The following code works:

```
HttpClient mHttpClient = null;
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
registry.register(new Scheme("https",  SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());
final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
```

Basically, using this `mHttpClient` when making the web service calls does not rise any error or complaints and works as expected. However, I've seen implementations like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749867/379865) which have a more secure approach.

My question is: by using the `DefaultHttpClient` simple as in the code above, could it rise some problems where on some devices the certificate may not be recognized as valid? Or better, should I go with the stored keystore as in the answer above?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting it. Above solution is wrong because it trusts *all* https calls from your app? Solution: trust only this particular certificate from your server?

Comment: agreed with mklimek - I did had to do this before with okhttp3 using [this sort of approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103174/does-okhttp-support-accepting-self-signed-ssl-certs)